# Better method: MergeParams

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a better way to do this? I'm trying to possibly shorten the method and improve it.

```
public static string MergeParams(string[] Params, int Start)
{
    var Merged = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = Start; i < Params.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > Start)
            Merged.Append(" ");
        Merged.Append(Params[i]);
    }

    return Merged.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `return string.Join(" ", Params.Skip(Start));`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string MergeParams(string[] Params, int Start) =>
    string.Join(" ", Params.Skip(Start));
```